# Generating standard records for ID for default category when few records are not coming from source in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have source table where particular ID is having 4 category, they may have all 4 category records or may have 1 or 2 or 3 category coming from the source.

Sample table structure of input.

[image]

Now from above input data we don't have data for ID 124 for category A & D coming from the source,
I need to generate those records in order to do some default calculations for those 2 category.

Output as below

[image]

Thanks !

Comment: Don't use images as tables, there are [many drawbacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) associated to it here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can apply a `LEFT JOIN` between combinations of ids and categories (`CROSS JOIN`) and your table. On missing matches, you use:

- `COALESCE` to assign 0 for "*Flag1*",
- `CASE` expression to craft DefaultCalc to be 'N' or 'Y'

```
SELECT ids.ID
       categories.Category,
       COALESCE(tab.Flag1, 0) AS Flag1,
       CASE WHEN tab.ID IS NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS DefaultCalc
FROM       (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM tab) ids
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Category FROM tab) categories
LEFT JOIN tab
       ON ids.ID = tab.ID AND categories.Category = tab.Category
```

---

Edit: What if I have no input and I want to populate?

You need to hardcode all your values inside your "*ids*" and "*categories*" subqueries.

```
SELECT ids.ID
       categories.Category,
       COALESCE(tab.Flag1, 0) AS Flag1,
       CASE WHEN tab.ID IS NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS DefaultCalc
FROM       (SELECT 123 AS id UNION ALL
                   124                ) ids
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'A' AS Category UNION ALL
            SELECT 'B'             UNION ALL
            SELECT 'C'             UNION ALL
            SELECT 'D'                      ) categories
LEFT JOIN tab
       ON ids.ID = tab.ID AND categories.Category = tab.Category
```

Comment: How will this query populate the missing category in case the all the records are not in the table doesnt have the default category needed. In above case I have given the reference for input, in case the categories are missing even for the first ID than I guess the query will not get the default records.

Comment: You need to hardcode your values then. Check the updated answer.

Comment: You can use specific generating functions only if your values are sequential by chance.

Comment: I think distinct id subquery should work as is, the modified category query looks good now, may be I will try that. What i was thinking was having a seperate table for category itself and do the cross join that way I have much cleaner query and easily maintainable in future. Thanks for the answer will try it and accept the answer.